# Bad Data Binding Oracle Trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have two tables called Projects and Opportunity. I want my triggers to fire when the status of Opportunity becomes 'P'. Then I want to increase project_code by 100 and grab some data from opportunity column and insert into Project table. 
I have my trigger written below and that gives me a bad data binding error. How do I fix that error? 
Thanks in advance. 
[image]

```
create or replace trigger proj_creator
   after insert or update on opportunity
   for each row
begin
   if :new.status = :p
   then
      insert into projects
         (project_code
         ,project_name
         ,client_id
         ,project_start_date
         ,project_end_date
         ,project_status
         ,pm_emp_id)
      values
         (:old.project_code auto_increment + 100
         ,:old.opp_name
         ,:old.client_id
         ,current_date
         ,add_months(date '2017-10-10', 48)
         ,'I'
         ,44444);
   end if;
end;
```

Comment: Your question does not appear to contain a question

Comment: Sorry. I edited my question.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your string comparison looks wrong

```
IF :new.status =: P 
THEN
```

Should probably be

```
IF :new.status = 'P'
THEN
```

Does your opportunity table contain a PROJECT_CODE column? Is it case sensitive? If so put the exact case in " quotes "

I've never seen someone write `:old.column_name AUTO_INCREMENT +x` as part of an insert statement. What are you expecting this set of words to do? (It looks like a column definition has been badly copied)

Comment: Opportunity table does not contain project_code. That is the reason I want to generate new project_code increasing from the last value by +100 then insert into Projects table. Project_code is a primary key in the project table. It is not a case sensitive.

Comment: "Opportunity table does not contain project_code." That's why you get the error message. :old.project_code does not exist.

Comment: If opportunity doesn't contain projectcode, then you cannot reference it in e :old row values. If you're trying to form a new primary key value for projects, use a sequence or something. If projects and opportunities are joined on some column, it is THAT opportunities column you should use as project code. Show your table structure and explain the relationships or show the foreign key code too